# Update errors after pressing "install"

Tags: updates

When I click install on updates the progress bar goes only halfway

I used these commands but nothing .

1.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.
```

results:

```
reading package list... DONE.
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock-open (11: resource temporarily unavailable. 
E: unable to lock directory/var/apt/lists
```

2.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

results :

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      berusky2-data cuyo-data libalut0 libgles1-mesa libmikmod3 libsdl-mixer1.2
      linux-headers-4.4.0-67 linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70
      linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-71
      linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72
      linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75
      linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-77
      linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic
      linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
      linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic
      linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic
      linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
      linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic
      linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-67-generic
      linux-signed-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-71-generic
      linux-signed-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-75-generic
      linux-signed-image-4.4.0-77-generic
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
    dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
     package software-properties-common is not ready for configuration
     cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     software-properties-common
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

3.

```
sudo apt autoremove  
        Remove:
          berusky2-data cuyo-data libalut0 libgles1-mesa libmikmod3 libsdl-mixer1.2
          linux-headers-4.4.0-67 linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70
          linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-71
          linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72
          linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75
          linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-77
          linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic
          linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
          linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic
          linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic
          linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
          linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic
          linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-67-generic
          linux-signed-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-71-generic
          linux-signed-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-75-generic
          linux-signed-image-4.4.0-77-generic
        0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 36 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
        1 not fully installed or removed.
        Need to get 0 B/9452 B of archives.
        After this operation, 2214 MB disk space will be freed.
        Progress: [ 36%] [######################....................................] 
        debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
        (Reading database ... 436345 files and directories currently installed.)
        Removing berusky2-data (0.9-1) ...
        Removing cuyo-data (2.0.0brl1-3) ...
        Removing libalut0:amd64 (1.1.0-5) ...
        Removing libgles1-mesa:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
        Removing libsdl-mixer1.2:amd64 (1.2.12-11build1) ...
        Removing libmikmod3:amd64 (3.3.8-2) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic (4.4.0-67.88) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-67 (4.4.0-67.88) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic (4.4.0-70.91) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-70 (4.4.0-70.91) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic (4.4.0-71.92) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-71 (4.4.0-71.92) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic (4.4.0-72.93) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-72 (4.4.0-72.93) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic (4.4.0-75.96) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-75 (4.4.0-75.96) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic (4.4.0-77.98) ...
        Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-77 (4.4.0-77.98) ...
        Removing linux-signed-image-4.4.0-67-generic (4.4.0-67.88) ...
        Generating grub configuration file ...
        Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-79-generic
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-67-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-67-generic
        Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
        done
        Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic (4.4.0-67.88)
```

.. etc  ...more errors .

Comment: Go back to 1. and try the two commands, one at the time, again. It was a temporary error it said.

Comment: The first point fails because it can't get a lock. If you are absolutely sure that no apt-thingie are running (eventually after a reboot) you can delete the lock-file (`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock-open`) and try once more.

Comment: Where does `udo` come from ? Did you meanto write `sudo ..`as in your question ans my comment ?

Comment: Pleas start from the beginning again, one command at the time (not with && inbetween) and update your question wuth the output.

Comment: really lost. i dont know how to manage my account.  i tried to delete the whole question (and repost)  but i cant find out how. meanwhile after reboot last days i get that ''software is up to date' but when an update appeared it stuck again. Now it says is up to date again. I ll keep the command anyway. THANKS AGAIN .   Soren A

Answer (score 0):

try running:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```